# rails 3 model associations model with rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

Could some 1 help me please with associations in rails app. This is my models:

```
class Catalog < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
    has_many :parent_catalogs
end


class ParentCatalog < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :catalog_id, :name
    has_many :child_catalogs
    belongs_to :catalog
end


class ChildCatalog < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :parent_catalog_id
    has_many :products
    belongs_to :parent_catalog
end


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :child_catalog_id, :name
  belongs_to :child_catalog
      # Ex
      rails_admin do
        field :name
        field :child_catalog do
          # How ((
        end
      end
end
```

Question is: how can i make child_catalog field look like:
Catalog.name + ParentCatalog.name + ChildCatalog.name
in Product edit menu...

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your ChildCatalog  model

```
def self.fullname
 self.parent_catelog.catelog.name + self.parent_catelog.name + self.name

end
```